# caught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@lit/reactive-element". while trying to import litElement

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, lit

I try to create a simple web component using lit. Here is my index.html import code

```
import {LitElement, html} from '../../node_modules/lit-element/lit-element.js';
```

I am using releative path here to lit-element.js.
here is the project structure:

```
/node_modules
  /lit-element
  /other-library
/myComponents
   my-element.js
   index.html
```

when I try to run the index file I got this error:

> caught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "@lit/reactive-element". Relative references must start with either
> "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: How are you serving the `index.html` and js files? You need some kind of plugin to resolve the bare specifiers into the correct location in `node_modules` like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve